# Why Pycharm does not apply Python highlighting to urls.py?

Tags: python, pycharm

Why is `urls.py` treated as a `.txt` file and not as a `.py`? I tried to remove and re-create the file and even reinstall the program but it doesn't work.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dq6E.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these steps:

1. (from OSX): PyCharm → Preferences → IDE Settings → File Types
2. Select the affected File Type from the list on the top half of this dialog box, Recognized File Types (in my case, Text Files)
3. Listed in the second half of the dialog box, Registered Patterns were the names of the files that I was having naming/syntax issues with. I clicked on each of those and then clicked on the - for each in turn to remove them from the Registered Patterns list.
4. Click Apply
5. Sigh of relief when the syntax highlighting returns and the icon changes back to that of a python file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows machine.

Use `rename` command.

> rename filename.py.txt filename.py

And If it is a Linux machine use `mv` command followed by filename using autocomplete option

> $ mv oldfilename filename.py